# Hide HTML element with CSS (not with ID or Class)

Tags: php, html, css

I want to hide some elements that don't have ID or Class.
I'm trying to edit a platform with encrypted php code, so there is no option to edit it manually.

```
<a href="somelink;returnUrl=somelink" data-identity="buttonApplications" class="tool-block">
```

How do I hide this element? Can I call it through "**data-identity**"? any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Use [Attribute Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

```css
[data-identity="buttonApplications"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="somelink;returnUrl=somelink" data-identity="buttonApplications" class="tool-block">click me</a>
```